# surface vs differentiable manifold

Tags: manifolds, surfaces

Every surface is a smooth manifold, but the reciprocal is verified?

some concrete example of a differentiable manifold is not surface?

Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A surface is simply a two-dimensional manifold. However, some subtlety arises if you distinguish "topological manifolds" (Hausdorff, second-countable, locally Euclidean topological spaces), "differentiable manifolds" (with additional global differential structure), and "smooth manifolds" (where the structure is smooth, i.e. infinitely differentiable). See, for example, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).

Usually a surface is [defined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface) as a two-dimensional topological manifold; the answer might depend on context, in particular your definitions of "surface" and "smooth manifold".

Comment: thanks for responding. I'm working with this definition of "surface": differentiable surface class $C^k$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and dimension $m$, assertions would be true for this definition?

Comment: @helmonio: I'd call that a "$m$-dimensional $C^k$ submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$", which is an $m$-dimensional $C^k$ manifold. (Typically "smooth" means $C^\infty$).

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis And according to Wikipedia (which references a paper of Whitney), every $C^{k}$ manifold can be assigned a smooth $C^{\infty}$ structure. Thus it seems helmonio's surfaces (your $C^{k}$ manifolds) and smooth, $C^{\infty}$ manifolds are in fact the same.

Comment: The link is here: http://www.jstor.org/stable/1968482

Comment: Yes. It's important to remember, however, that the embedding in $\mathbb R^n$ will not necessarily be $C^\infty$.

Answer (score 4):

The term surface is usually used to indicate a $2$-dimensional manifold (or even a $2$-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$). Any manifold of higher or lower dimension would not be a surface.

More generally, the term hypersurface of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is used to denote a $(n-1)$-submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: Forgiveness my definition is "differentiable surface" that which at every point has a parameter that is a homeomorphism and immersion of a Euclidean space.

Comment: Instead a differentiable manifold has cards that leave the set coordinates to a Euclidean space but not have to be differentiable, hence my question